# How to press "Next" on the last EditText on the screen and return to the first EditText

Tags: java, android, ime

I haven't seen this before and I just figured it out, so I thought I'd write this QnA. Let me know if you think this is a duplicate.

**Question:**

How can I make it so that when the user is focused on the *last* `EditText` on the screen, it will give them the option on the soft keyboard to press **Next** and then will return to the *first* `EditText` on the screen?

For example:

[image]

Notice in the bottom right corner is says "Next". I want it to say "Next" like that instead of "Done" and I also want it to return to (focus on) the **a** `EditText` when I press "Next", currently focused on the **c** `EditText`.

Comment: isn't it simply android:nextFocusDown="@+id/something" ?

Comment: @njzk2 I tried that as well as `android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/a"` but I couldn't get it working. Leave an answer if you can, or just leave a comment with what to do and I'll update my answer and credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `EditText` XML properties for `EditText` **c**, add this property to it:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

This will make it so the bottom right corner of the soft keyboard will be the "Next" button instead of "Done".

Then, set up a listener for when the "Next" button is pressed on the `EditText` **c**.

```
EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a);
EditText c = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);

c.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        // if the user pressed the "Next" button on the soft keyboard
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
        {
            a.requestFocus(); // change the focus to the 'a' EditText
        }
        return true; // keep the keyboard up
    }
});
```

And that's it.

Comment: Some combination of this answer should give your desired effect.